# Link for reviewing

Tags: support, review-queues

Where can I find a link for a reviewing? If I enter the link directly in browser, then I can see a page for reviewing (I'm only allowed to review Documentation), but I cannot find a link to https://stackoverflow.com/review on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you see [this icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f67wb.png) to the right of your user name in the top bar?

Comment: No, I don't see this icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are links to the documentation review queue in the different Documentation pages.

Once you get the [Access Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) privilege, the help drop down in the header will change into a review one.

Comment: I have not this privilege, but I allowed to review the docs. I can not find any links to http://stackoverflow.com/review, also on docs pages. Can you paste a screenshot?

Comment: So I haven't understood from your answer, is it bug or feature, that I have not a Link to review page, despite I can review a Documentation?

Comment: @Rekshino - is it by design. The documentation reviews are embedded in the pages that require reviews.